# Jenkins Scripting using Groovy

Tags: groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

How to start with Jenkins scripting using groovy as the scripting language? where can i find a proper documentation of all the methods and how to use them that i can use to automate Jenkins using groovy?

Answer (score 0):

At first, refer to the plugin itself, it has nice and detailed explanations: [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)

Than just learn a bit about Groovy as a language and start using it.

Add `Groovy postbuild` action and type the script content.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried some basic scripts in jenkins script console. But some of the scripts are not working. for example :                   import hudson.model.*
scms =  FreeStyleProject.getSCMs()
println(scms)                                                                                               i am trying to print all the scms configured in jenkins. But i am getting an error. can you tell me what is wrong with the code and what will fix it?

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.getSCMs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getSCMs(), getScm(), getACL(), getACL(), setScm(hudson.scm.SCM), getName() .......

Answer (score 0):

The [Scripler](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) plugin is a powerful plugin that let's you run your groovy code from any build step. (it can even be used to code Jenkins dynamic parameters in the UI!)

There are two additional advantages of using this plugin:

1. **You can test your groovy code on your actual Jenkins server**:
   After you install the plugin, go to: "Manage Jenkins" --> "Scriptler" or "YOUR_SERVER_URL/scriptler" and click "Add a new Script". Save it with an initial code something like `println "Hello Scriptler!"` and click "submit". you will now be able to run your script for testing by clicking on the small Terminal icon.
2. **It has a fair share of already made scripts created by the people in the community**:  Visit https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts

Comment: I want to access/read all txt files (including sub dir of workspace as well) using groovy postbuild. How to do that?